# Tcl -- Tcllib HTTP: geturl

Tags: http, google-app-engine, https, tcl

I'm having trouble trying to implement tcllib's http package.

One issue that I am having is that after running the following code:

```
set fp [::http::geturl "https://google.com"]
```

I get the following error:

```
error reading "sock23": software caused connection abort
    while executing
"::http::geturl "https://google.com""
    ("uplevel" body line 55)
    invoked from within
"uplevel {
    #package require yajltcl
package require sha256
package require base64
package require http 1.0
package require tls
package require pki
```

Is there something wrong with my brain?

Comment: Your brain is not at fault, but why are you using http 1.0 (very old code!) and which _exact_ version of the tls package are you using? Google is fairly sensitive to some things.

Comment: I have tried to put the v2.5 of http, but it seems like the server that I am running the script on only support v1.0. I am fairly a noob at tcl. . How would I find the package version that I am using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running the following command before performing ::http::register made my script work:

```
tls::init -tls1 true -ssl2 false -ssl3 false
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to register tls protocol first to open https links, try this command:

```
http::register https 443 [list ::tls::socket -tls1 1]
```